# How to remove a directory in wordpress using Filesystem_API

Tags: php, wordpress, file

I am using WordPress 4.8.1

I am trying to remove a directory from theme setting, but neither getting any error nor any success.
Even PHP error log has not logged data about it, My WP_DEBUG is on.

```
$wp_filesystem_base = WP_Filesystem_Base();
$wp_filesystem_base->rmdir(dirname($file_path), true);
```

The class is not undefined for sure as I could have got some error, still I used a class_exists to check it and it is available where I am using.

please let me know, if I am doing it wrong or need any thing  more about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended with using a core php function, I believe it is a workaround, but will be useful for someone for who the above code or

```
$wp_filesystem_direct = WP_Filesystem_Direct();
$wp_filesystem_direct->rmdir(dirname($file_path), true);
```

will not work. You can use this

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
       if (is_dir($dir)) { 
         $objects = scandir($dir); 
         foreach ($objects as $object) { 
           if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
             if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") self::rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object); 
           } 
         } 
         reset($objects); 
         rmdir($dir); 
       } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since a WordPress' core methods working answer is missing here, I propose this complete solution that sums up all the other aswers.

```
require_once ( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php' );
$fileSystemDirect = new WP_Filesystem_Direct(false);
$fileSystemDirect->rmdir($dir, true);
```

**Summary:**

- You can't use `WP_Filesystem_Base` because does not really implement the method rmdir; it's just an interface.
- You must require `class-wp-filesystem-base.php` because it's a dependency of `WP_Filesystem_Direct`
- You can always use your own `rrmdir` as someone proposed, but you don't have to add additional code to be maintained when a feature is already available in core;
- The `false` argument passed to the constructor is just because the $arg param is needed but not used as explained in official WP's documentation.

Comment: This answer helped a lot. Just be mindful that on linux system you need to use forward slash '/' instead of backslash '\'. Also, `ABSPATH` has an trailing slash. So require should be `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php' );`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use `WP_Filesystem_Direct` class

`WP_Filesystem_Base::rmdir` implementation:

```
public function rmdir( $path, $recursive = false ) {
    return false;
}
```

You can see, that this code is not working with real FS :)

So, `WP_Filesystem_Direct::rmdir` actually do the job.

Comment: Why you think so, if WP_Filesystem_Base is accessible and the method belongs to the class, why I need to use WP_Filesystem_Direct class. second part is, still I have tried it and with no success. Thank you for your effort. Please let me know, if you have any other suggestion.

Comment: Because methods, that you believe should work, just return false? :)

It seems, that WP_Filesystem_Base need to be abstract, so each child classes have own special implementation of these methods for local fs or ssh. About second. Have you checked that is path is correct? What is return value from `WP_Filesystem_Direct::rmdir` with yours args?

Comment: Actually the method is non static and codex has not described as correctly. But even using Class instance is not making it working 

Comment: no idea why I am getting false, so it seems it is unable to delete this folder for some reason.

Comment: Up-voting your answer for your effort and I also think it is right direction, in that case my code is also correct, no idea it did not worked for me, I am also posting my solution, I used core php to solve this issue at last.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work like this:

```
/**
 * Deletes a directory, using the WordPress Filesystem API
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return void
 * @author Rasso Hilber <mail@rassohilber.com>
 */
function delete_directory(string $path) {
  // make it work from the frontend, as well
  require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
  // this variable will hold the selected filesystem class
  global $wp_filesystem;
  // this function selects the appropriate filesystem class
  WP_Filesystem();
  // finally, you can call the 'delete' function on the selected class,
  // which is now stored in the global '$wp_filesystem'
  $wp_filesystem->delete($path, true);
}
```

Comment: can not check now as it is too old, but seems fine to me, only concern is you can check if you need to reset $wp_filesystem object after this operation.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
require_once ( ABSPATH . '\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-filesystem-direct.php' );
$fileSystemDirect = new WP_Filesystem_Direct(false);
$fileSystemDirect->rmdir($dir, true);
```

Or simply:

```
WP_Filesystem();
global $wp_filesystem;
$wp_filesystem->rmdir($dir, true);
```